# CakePHP X hasMany Y, find X that has Y.name = "value1" AND at the same time has Y.name = "value2"

Tags: mysql, cakephp

So my model association is as follows:

Person hasMany Award

Person columns: id, name
Award columns: id, person_id, name

So people can have many awards, but I want to retrieve only those specific people that have two different awards at the same time. Is there a way to achieve this with find method?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [subqueries](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) at the end of the page. You basically need a subquery because you need to query the Award table twice to match value1 and value2.

---

*Edit :* **Example code**

```
$conditionsSubQuery['`Award`.`name`'] = 'value2';
$dbo = $this->Person->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array( '`Person2`.`id`'),
        'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->Person),
        'alias' => 'Person2',
        'limit' => null,
        'offset' => null,
        'joins' => array(),
        'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
        'order' => null,
        'group' => null
    ),
    $this->Person
);
$subQuery = ' `Person`.`id` IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';
$subQueryExpression = $dbo->expression($subQuery);
$conditions[] = array('Award.name' => 'value1');
$conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;
$this->Person->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```

I haven't tested it and it might not work, but you got the idea.

---

*Edit 2:* **To answer your comment**

So basically what you want as an SQL result is

```
select 
    users.id 
from 
    users 
left join 
    awards 
where 
    awards.name in ('award1', 'award2', 'award3', 'award4') 
group by 
    awards.name 
having 
    count(awards.name) = 4
```

To achieve that you may do it that way :

```
$awards = array('award1', 'award2', 'award3', 'award4');

$this->Person->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
               'table' =>'awards',
               'alias' => 'Award',
               'type' => 'LEFT',
               'conditions' => 'Award.person_id = person.id'
             )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Award.name' => $awards,
        ),
        'group' => array('Award.name HAVING '.count($awards))
    )
);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it can't be limited to only two conditions (two awards in this example). Does it mean that in order to find people who have 10 different awards I would have to query Awards 10 times?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way of doing that doesn't suffer the previous problem. It's even faster from SQL point of view I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$persons = $this->Person->find('all', array(
                           'recursive' => -1,
                           'conditions' => array(
                              'AND' => array('Award.name' => 'Award 1', 'Award.name' => 'Award 3')
                            ),
                           'joins' => array(
                                array(
                                   'table' =>'awards',
                                   'alias' => 'Award',
                                   'type' => 'LEFT',
                                   'conditions' => 'Award.person_id = person.id'
                                 )
                            )
                      )
                 );
```

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for, will test it soon. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is going to work as it will produce an `IN (value1, value2)` condition. Which can be simplified in an `OR`, which is not what @user1399007 want. He says he wants user that have both awards.

Comment: In this case it's not what I'm looking for :/. I want it to be an AND statement.

Comment: @user1399007 get you AND statement in my updated answer and for your information my previous and current code both do the same job